# Regex - match all strings with specific exceptions

Tags: regex

I have a lot of strings which have similar values.
I need to write a regex that will keep all values except those that start with a specific substring, anyone know how I can do this.

For example, assume my string values are :

```
foo_bar
foo_baz
foo_bar_baz
foo_baz_bar
bar_baz
bar_foo
```

I can write a regex that will capture all of the above strings easily :

```
(foo_.*|bar_.*)
```

But supposing I have reasons for dropping anything that contains "foo_baz" and keep all the others.
i.e. my results would be :

```
foo_bar
foo_bar_baz
bar_baz
bar_foo
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this without explicitly listing each of the strings I want to keep?

Thanks.

Comment: Which language/tool? Please read the ['regex' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: Try: `^(?!.*foo_baz)(?:foo|bar)_.*`

Comment: Does your laguage/tool support the use of look-arounds? Then something like this might work: `(foo_(?!baz).*|bar_.*)`

Comment: Thanks for replies.

I can't use startswith() or similar as it's not being done in code.
The regex I'm trying to define is part of Prometheus config which apparently uses RE2 syntax.

I've never come across negative lookahead before, but will look at that option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!foo_baz).*$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/jBCSjR/1

Or, depending on your programming language, it could be easier to filter out values using `startsWith()` or any equivalent.